# making text go to new text

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

So I really don't know how to word this, but I'm trying to create a sequence when someone clicks on one of the three buttons it will go to new text after they press the button. The thing is I don't know how to start it. Do I need to create another template or could I use the same one that I'm using? 
HTML:

```
<div id="app">

    <barista-template></barista-template>
</div>


    <!--template for customer-->
<script type="text/x-template" id="b-template">
    <div>
        <div>{{showText}}</div>
        <button v-on:click="choose('drip')">Drip</button>
        <button v-on:click="choose('frenchpress')">French Press</button>
        <button v-on:click="choose('aeropress')">Aeropress</button>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="c-template">
    <div>
        <div>{{showText2}}</div>
    </div>
</script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
Vue.component("customer-template",{
   template:"#c-template",
    data:function (){
       return{
           order_type:"",
       }
    },
    computed:{
        showText2 (){
            if(this.order_type === '') return '';
            return 'waiting for' + this.order_type
        }

    }
});
Vue.component("barista-template",{
    template: "#b-template",
    data: function () {
        return{
            order_type:"",
            order_value: "",
        }
    },
    computed: {
        showText () {
            if(this.order_type === '') return '';
            return 'One ' + this.order_type + ' that would be ' + this.order_value
        }
    },
    methods: {
        choose: function (order_type) {
            this.order_type = order_type;

            if (this.order_type == "drip") {
                this.order_value = "$10";
            }
            if (this.order_type == "frenchpress") {
                this.order_value = "$20";
            }
            if (this.order_type == "aeropress") {
                this.order_value = "$30";
            }
        }
    },
});
new Vue ({
    el:"#app",
    data:function () {
        return{
            showing:true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by `go to new text` ,, your code works fine,, do you refere to some tween or effect to slide text? if you do please share similar or example URL to get the feeling of what you need..

Comment: sorry about that so when someone presses  one of the three buttons [showText2] is suppose to come right after it which says : 'waiting for' + this.order_type

Comment: see my answer if that's what you need

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for but it supposes to be once some presses one of the three buttons then the waiting for drip would show up Example: customer press drip [one drip that would be $10] then the new text would replace it saying [waiting for drip] so it just replaces the old text with the new text

Comment: so I'm guessing I need a set time method ??

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? one template and I added new property

```js
Vue.component("barista-template",{
    template: "#b-template",
    data: function () {
        return{
            order_type:"",
            order_value: "",
        }
    },
    computed: {
        showText () {
            if(this.order_type === '') return '';
            return 'One ' + this.order_type + ' that would be ' + this.order_value
        },
        showText2 (){
            if(this.order_type === '') return '';
            return 'waiting for ' + this.order_type
        }
    },
    methods: {
        choose: function (order_type) {
            this.order_type = order_type;

            if (this.order_type == "drip") {
                this.order_value = "$10";
            }
            if (this.order_type == "frenchpress") {
                this.order_value = "$20";
            }
            if (this.order_type == "aeropress") {
                this.order_value = "$30";
            }
        }
    },
});
new Vue ({
    el:"#app",
    data:function () {
        return{
            showing:true
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
    <barista-template></barista-template>
</div>




    <!--template for customer-->
<script type="text/x-template" id="b-template">
    <div>
        <div>{{showText}}</div>
        <button v-on:click="choose('drip')">Drip</button>
        <button v-on:click="choose('frenchpress')">French Press</button>
        <button v-on:click="choose('aeropress')">Aeropress</button>
        <div>{{showText2}}</div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="c-template">
    <div>
        <div>{{showText2}}</div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for but it supposes to be once some presses one of the three buttons then the waiting for drip would show up Example: customer press drip [one drip that would be $10] then the new text would replace it saying [waiting for drip].

Comment: so I'm guessing I need a set time method ??

Comment: yes, I would suggest to put ID on that div where you'd like to replace text, and then use `setTimeout` to replace text

Comment: so how would it replace the other text if  I create an ID?